# how to call method from one adapter to current adapter activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to call a method from one adapter activity to another adapter activity?

I have list view when I press item in list view I am getting popup window with check boxes by selecting check box and pressing ok. I have to disable item in the main list but the item is disabling in popup window list the main list loads in another adapter so I think by disable item there and attach to check box it may work. so please help me.

Main Activity:

```
listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     newListitems2.clear();
                  newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

                    // ArrayList newListitems2 = new ArrayList();
                     //newListitems2.add(itemsList1);
                     dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
                        dialog.show();


                        list1=(ListView )dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

                        ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this,newListitems2);
                        list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

                        Button okButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
                        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                 });
                            Button cancelButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
                    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }



                        });
                        return true;

                 }
                            });
```

This is my main activity where on clicking item dialog appears.

dialog adapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        ViewHolder holder;
                        String item = null, qty = null;
                        if (convertView == null) {
                            holder = new ViewHolder();
                            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
                            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
                            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                            holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
                            holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
                             holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
                            convertView.setTag(holder);

                        } else {

                            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        parentobjid=newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
                        if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
                        {
                            holder.name.setText("   " +newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                            holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                                    .getQuantityDisplay()));
                            holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                                .getQuantityDisplay()));
                        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

                        holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
                        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                    boolean isChecked) {


                                int position=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();


                                  newListitems.get(position).setChecked(!newListitems.get(position).isChecked());


                            }
                        });
                        if(newListitems.get(position).isChecked()){
                            holder.name.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));

                            }else{
                            holder.name.setEnabled(true);
                            }
```

This is adapter in which list along with check boxes is loaded.

List Adapter :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        ViewHolder holder;
                        String item = null, qty = null;
                        if (convertView == null) {
                            holder = new ViewHolder();
                            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
                            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
                            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                            holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
                            holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
                             holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
                            convertView.setTag(holder);

                        } else {

                            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        parentobjid=newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
                        if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
                        {
                            holder.name.setText("   " +newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                            holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                                    .getQuantityDisplay()));
                            holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                                .getQuantityDisplay()));
                        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

This is my adapter in which main list is loaded. If I select the check box and press ok I want to disable or change color of item in main list but it is changing in dialog box list.

Please help me

Comment: post some code.

Comment: use intent to pass the data to other activity and the use it in other activity

Comment: Use event bus to send an event from one adapter to otheradapter and process ur logic there. Best way is to write a logic inside main adapter class by populating popup menu in main adapter